# How to put dynamic data coming from the backend into attr() jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I need to put a couple of attributes from Javascript since I am unable to edit the file where the main code is, which is a jsp file (don't ask me why).

If you see the element, it should look like this:

```
<a class="callBtn dartClick callfix"
   name="contact_us_purchase" dartId="2014_HLI_HLG_Home_Call_Us_CTA_OnClick"
   href="tel:1-<loans:fmtPhone phone="${contactPhoneNumber}"
   separator="-" areaCodeParens="false" />">Call</a>
```

And this is my jquery code so far:

```
var contact = $("[name='contact_us_equity']");
contact.attr({
  'href': 'tel:1-<loans:fmtPhone phone="${contactPhoneNumber}"',
  'separator': '-',
  'areaCodeParens': 'false'
});
```

the problem with this, is that `href` element is rendering as it is so in the html looks like this:

```
<a class="callBtn dartClick callfix"
   name="contact_us_equity" dartid="2014_HLI_HLG_Home_Call_Us_CTA_OnClick"
   href="tel:1-&lt;loans:fmtPhone phone=&quot;${contactPhoneNumber}&quot;"
   separator="-" areacodeparens="false">Call</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: $("a[name='contact_us_equity']");

Comment: You desired output is invalid. The `href` attribute does not close properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to store some arbitrary data properties inside HTML without them actually changing how the HTML element "looks & behaves".

To achieve this, you can use [`$().data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), for example:

```
var myData = 'tel:1-<loans:fmtPhone phone="${contactPhoneNumber}"';

$("[name='contact_us_equity']").data("href", myData);
```

You could also use `$().attr()`, using a `data-` prefix for all the new attributes:

```
var myData = 'tel:1-<loans:fmtPhone phone="${contactPhoneNumber}"';

$("[name='contact_us_equity']").attr("data-href", myData);
```

The only difference between them, is that the former one does not modify the DOM Tree itself - it stores the data inside jQuery's internal structures.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine..

```js
var contact = $("[name='contact_us_purchase']");
contact.attr({
  'href': 'tel:1-<loans:fmtPhone phone="${contactPhoneNumber}"',
  'separator': '-',
  'areaCodeParens': 'false'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a
   class="callBtn dartClick callfix"
   name="contact_us_purchase"
   dartId="2014_HLI_HLG_Home_Call_Us_CTA_OnClick"
   separator="- "
   areaCodeParens="false" />Call</a>
<br/>
(Right click and inspect to see the href)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(_ => {
  var contact = $('[name=contact_us_purchase]');
  contact.attr('href', 'tel:1-<loans:fmtPhone phone="${contactPhoneNumber}" separator="-" areaCodeParens="false" />');
  console.log(contact.attr('href'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="callBtn dartClick callfix" name="contact_us_purchase">Call</a>
```